# Docker Compose binding docker cli error: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /usr/local/bin/docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-in-docker

I've been binding the host docker socket and cli so that I can run docker and compose commands from within running containers for over a year without issue but since updating to docker version 20.10.7 and compose version 1.29.2 I can't get my containerised environment to launch without the following error:

**invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /usr/local/bin/docker**

Nothing has changed other than I updated Docker Desktop.

The location of the docker binary (symlink) on the host is still present:

`0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 aadams-mbp  staff  54  3 Aug  2018 /usr/local/bin/docker -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker`

The target of the symlink permissions look like this:

`133608 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  68405888  7 Jul 17:59 /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker`

This snippet is from my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
volumes: 
      # Bind docker CLI so can run docker commands
      # from inside the container. Double check the
      # location of the source binary on hosts that
      # are not Mac OS. Docker might be in /usr/bin/docker,
      # but on Mac OS it is at /usr/local/bin/docker.
      - type: bind
        source: /var/run/docker.sock
        target: /var/run/docker.sock
      - type: bind
        source: ${DOCKER_BIN_SRC}
        target: /usr/bin/docker
```

The ${DOCKER_BIN_SRC} is pulled in from a .env file (snippet):

```
##
# Docker bind
#
DOCKER_BIN_SRC=/usr/local/bin/docker
```

I am running on Mac OS Mojave version 10.14.6

Comment: This setup shouldn't have ever worked: you can only bind-mount configured directories on Docker Desktop for Mac (so not `/usr/local/...`) and a MacOS-binary won't work in a Linux container (as the comment notes).  If you need a `docker` binary, install one using an appropriate package manager (usually `apk` or `apt-get`) in your image's Dockerfile.

Comment: @DavidMaze, thanks for setting me straight. Of course MacOS binary wouldn't work in Linux - I completely overlooked that. No idea why it's never caused me an issue before. Adjusting my approach.